# What is the Pythonic way to remove "Bearer " from the HTTP authorization header

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have an Authorization header in a string like this:

```
Bearer [myawesometoken]
```

I don't want to tokenize using the space character because I want to require the string "Bearer" to be at the start of the string

What is the pythonic way to return just the token from the string?

Is there a regex matching function like PHP `preg_match()`?  Would this be the pythonic way to do it?

Comment: So what should happen if the string *doesn't* start with "Bearer"?

Comment: @Aran-Fey It should respond with "no match" so that I can return a 401 error.  I only want to support Bearer tokens.

Comment: This has a smell about it...are you *receiving* the request with this header, or are you *sending* a request with this header?

Comment: Receiving it in Django middleware

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted. It's a good question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the most Pythonic way of doing this would be to use the built-in [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method of `str` and [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
PREFIX = 'Bearer '

def get_token(header):
    if not header.startswith(PREFIX):
        raise ValueError('Invalid token')

    return header[len(PREFIX):]
```

I however would prefer [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to tokenize the header into a 3-tuple:

```
PREFIX = 'Bearer'

def get_token(header):
    bearer, _, token = header.partition(' ')
    if bearer != PREFIX:
        raise ValueError('Invalid token')

    return token
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wanted the pythonic way of doing it, this is really helpful.

Comment: What about using `str.split()`? It would eliminate the need for the intermediary `_` assignment.

Comment: `str.partition` guarantees a 3-tuple result, even if the separator isn't found in the string. `str.split` only splits if the separator is found in the input string (the amount of times the string may be split can be controlled using `maxsplit` parameter).

Answer (score 3):

Let say your authorization string is

```
Bearer mytoken
```

then u can extract token like this

```
import re
authorization_string="Bearer mytoken"
g = re.match("^Bearer\s+(.*)", authorization_string)

if g:
    # ur token
    print(g.group(1)
else:
    print("No token")
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the string always in this format?

```
header_string = 'Bearer [myawesometoken]'
token = header_string[8:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only want to support Bearer tokens so it's mandatory for the string to start with that.

Comment: Assume that I don't know what a Bearer token is, and then explain how you want your string modified. Please give example of original string and wanted output string.

Comment: It should be token = header_string[7:-1]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Python 3.10 or higher, you can use `match case` syntax:

```py
def get_token(header: str) -> str:
    match header.split(" "):
        case ["Bearer", token]:
            return token

    raise ValueError("Invalid token")
```